# Creating a flutter list tile with as many tiles as I have elements in a List i'm passing

Tags: flutter, dart

I am normally a Laravel frontend dev, and I'm trying to learn flutter and dart as an intro to mobile frontend. In laravel blade's html, when you want to create visual elements for each data you are feeding to the front it's exactly this: a for each loop that repeats the element but with different data. I undertsand Dart uses a different paradigm, and I am too stuck in the "laravel cone" and finding it difficult to implement solutions as it should be done in dart.
The way this is working now is: I've got some data I got in a post request, saving that in a Todo class and passing it as parameters to the renderer of the next view:

The Class

```
class Todo {
  String name;
  String lastacc;
  String created_at;
  String farmDoc;
  String farmName;
  String clientId;
  List farms;

  Todo(this.name, this.lastacc, this.created_at, this.farmDoc, this.farmName, this.farms, this.clientId);
}
```

The Function

```
Todo infoAcc = Todo(name, lastAcc, createdAcc, farmDoc, farmName, farms, id );
        Future.delayed(
          const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          () {
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => Farmlist(),
                    settings: RouteSettings(arguments: infoAcc)));
          },
        );
```

This is working nice, before the function I managed to get the variables correctly set and by debugging I know it's working fine; Now i have this other view, the Farmlist, where it should get de List farms and use it to generate several Tiles in a ListTile, each one with info from a different farm. It should be dynamic, as to show always the amount of tiles equivalent to the amount of elements in the array I pass, as different users will have a different amount of farms.

Any example or documentation i could read, or alternative solution is welcome. I've been struggling with this for quite the time now.

Comment: Note that the ask for suggestions on working code, doesnt belong to stack overflow. Consider posting this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ the next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ListView.builder widget,  you simply need to pass the array that you want to build and with the builder function you can create a widget that depends on the given data

For more information:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html
https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/long-lists